# Update item in DynamoDB using Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I want to update specific Item(Only One data from row),

How can I update item in DynamoDB.?

**login_id** is my primary key. I pass login_id and other boolean value.
I want to set boolean value true according to that login-id.

How can I do that?

I tried this code.

```
LinkedHashMap inputHashMap = (LinkedHashMap) input;

        login_id = (String) inputHashMap.get("login_id");
        isUserVerified = (Boolean) inputHashMap.get("isUserVerified");

        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient());

        Table tableUserDetails = dynamoDB.getTable(USER_DETAILS_TABLE);
        Table tableOtpStatus = dynamoDB.getTable(OTP_DETAILS_TABLE);

        UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("login_id", login_id);

        try{

            UpdateItemOutcome outcome = tableUserDetails.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
            System.out.println("UpdateItem succeeded:\n" + outcome.getItem().toJSONPretty());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

While executing above code I got below exception.

```
The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the update expression. Assuming *isUserVerified* is part of the primary key, it should be something like:

```
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
      .withPrimaryKey("login_id", login_id)
      .withUpdateExpression("set isUserVerified = :val")
      .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
         .withBoolean(":val", true));
```

If *isUserVerified* not part of the key then just remove it from the `.withPrimaryKey()` statement.

You can find more [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Java.03.html#GettingStarted.Java.03.03).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already solved problem same as this way. Thanks for  information.

Comment: Hey can you give me example, If I want to update more than one value based on login_id (Primary Key).

Comment: @ChiragSavsani may I know from which library I can get UpdateItemSpec?